# Recover data from a Samsung DVD recorder's hard drive

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery

I have a Samsung DVD recorder:

[image]

I want to recover data from its hard disk. I need to buy a SATA-to-USB adapter and connect the hard drive to power then to USB and mount it on my PC. I have done data recovery on formatted external hard disks many times.  My question is, do DVD recorders in general, and this DVD recorder in particular, have a file system similar to the file system of PCs?

- Samsung Hard disk model number HA252HI
- HDD P/N HA252HI/VDE

I ask, because in order to recover data, at least the way I learned and the way I do it, is to:

1. Make sure that the device filesystem is recognized by the PC
2. Format it
3. Recover the data
4. Reformat the device to its original filesystem

**I want to know two things:**

1. Will the DVD recorder be recognized by my PC?
2. Can I reformat it to its original filesystem after finishing my work?

My main concern is about this sentence from this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_video_recorder#File_formats.2C_resolutions_and_file_systems), the word `proprietary` worries me.

> DVRs usually record in proprietary file systems for copy protection,
>   although some can use FAT file systems.

Comment: It's probably some standard Linux filesystem. Why do you want to format it, then recover data? Can't you just copy what you want or "recover" before formatting? It sounds much safer.

Comment: DO NOT FORMAT THE DEVICE FILESYSTEM - This will wipe out data, probably important data.  If it were me, my first port of call would be to get a same or larger size disk and do a bit copy (using gnu ddrescue or similar), and then work off the copy.

Comment: @gronostaj sometimes the entire filesystem is corrupt because of some error, you have to format it in order to read data, like say you inserted your external hard disk to xbox 360, the xbox is reading it and you shut it down, everything will be gone, even data recovery software can't read it unless you format it to something like fat. But I'll try to do that

Comment: @davidgo I'll try to do that tomorrow, I'll try to avoid  it if possible

Comment: @Fischer - My apologies for contradicting you, but I think its important.  Data recovery software does not require a disk to be formatted to read it - and you should not format (the original) disk when trying to do data recovery as it can only make things worse.  When you format a disk you are telling it to rewrite the filesystem setup structures on the disk and usually overwriting key information useful in recovering disks.  Data recovery software can definately read disks which are not formatted - indeed the popular photorec software ONLY does this (ie it ignores the formatting information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have experience with that disk model, but the Samsung HA252HI hard disk is mentioned
in several places as available for use on PCs.

The driver site driveragent.com refers to a "SAMSUNG HA252HI USB Device" in [this page](http://drivers.for.sony-corporation.vgn-fs415s.driveragent.com/2393347083233/Microsoft-Windows-Vista-Home-Premium?PHPSESSID=k8mdchrtj1tmo4h0ks08euu2v0).
The disk is marked as
"Your computer has the latest driver for this device, no updates are necessary".

If one can believe this website, the disk might be formatted in a standard format and you are in luck.
What worries me is its mention as a USB device, while in your case it's you that will supply
the USB enclosure, which adds some uncertainty to the project.

It's probably worth the effort to try and see.
Just try to avoid formatting the disk if not absolutely required.

Even if you can see the disk and the files on it, there is of course no guarantee that you could
use these files. Some recorders use non-standard video formats or even encrypt the files.

Comment: uhmm the first part of your answer is encouraging, unlike the second part :) i'll try to do it tomorrow and will let you know how it goes and if i have further questions, right now I don't have SATA to usb cable  :)

Comment: @Fischer Is there any way you can connect the recorder's hard drive using the SATA interface only? Eliminating the SATA-to-USB adapter would remove one variable and possibly improve your odds of a successful recovery.

Comment: @Twisty here are some images, if i could, how to do it? [1](http://i.imgur.com/9CptGqo.jpg), [2](http://i.imgur.com/JQXrHD3.jpg), [3](http://i.imgur.com/dz3Q22D.jpg)

Comment: @Fischer: The [HA252HI](http://www.hdsentinel.com/storageinfo_details.php?lang=en&model=SAMSUNG%20HA252HI) uses Serial-ATA/300 aka SATA II. If your motherboard has SATA II or III then you can add it as a secondary internal disk. Otherwise use a [Sata to IDE adapter](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Bidirectional-SATA-to-IDE-3-5-or-IDE-3-5-to-SATA-Adapter-Converter/1099394566.html) or a [USB to SATA Enclosure](http://www.amazon.com/Sabrent-2-5-Inch-External-Enclosure-EC-UK30/dp/B00LS31KQG/ref=sr_1_2?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1414877639) (these are just examples found on google which I never used myself).

Comment: What harrymc said, use power and data cables in your computer to connect the drive just like you would a regular hard drive. Any modern desktop computer will have the correct connections.